# No complete graphs could be bipartitle.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How do I prove that the above statement is false? Can anyone give me a hint or so on how to disprove the above statement?

Comment: Hint: Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be three distinct vertices in a complete graph. If the graph were bipartite, two of the vertices would be in the same component... (And also: Did this argument assume too much about the graph?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:** $K_2$ is bipartite.

Comment: Moreover, no complete graph with more than 2 vertices is bipartite, because of including an odd cycle.

Comment: Didn't think of that haha, thanks a lot!